# mysql stored procedure not working i have give the code below please help me

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

### hey this is procedure for writing contents of issue table to a temp table based on magazine id

`delimiter //`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `magazineCursor`()
BEGIN
DECLARE d INT default 0;
DECLARE magazine_id,issue_id,temp_id INT;
DECLARE issue_name VARCHAR(20);
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT  magazine_id FROM tbl_magazine limit 1 ;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET d=1;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '23000' SET d=1;
OPEN cur1;
lb: LOOP
    IF d=1 THEN
      LEAVE lb;
      END IF;
      IF NOT d=1 THEN
      FETCH cur1 INTO temp_id;
      SELECT magazine_id ,issue_id,issue_name   INTO magazine_id,issue_id,issue_name FROM tbl_magazine_issue  where magazine_id=temp_id and os_select=2 order by  issue_date    desc limit 1;
        insert into temp_magazine_table values(magazine_id,issue_id,issue_name);
       END IF;
      END LOOP;
      CLOSE cur1;
      END//
```

Comment: It would greatly help if you could include what version of MySQL and if you are trying to execute this through phpMyAdmin or command line. If you are using phpMyAdmin, what version. Since it does vary depending on installation and version.

Comment: Try to avoid opening cursors, and use a INSERT...SELECT statement instead.

Comment: 1. No Details about the error, 2. Title should be something like "Procedure not writing contents to temp table" 3. The body should say something like " I am having issues with this stored procedure. I get the following errors XXXX when I run it with the following parameters XX ' etc...   I did not down vote you because you seem to be new to the forum, but you are going to get many down votes if you dont format your questions better :).

Comment: Why this kolaveri di!! Read this: stackoverflow.com/faq "Not working" means WHAT?

Comment: phpmyadmin version 3.2.0.1 ,when the procedure is called it traps to an infinite loop @James Williams

Comment: @user710502 1 this is my 1st post forgive

Comment: @Arun Killu What version of MySQL?

Comment: @James Williams mysql version 5.1.37

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your LOOP you have no way to check if it is done creating a temp table.

You need to set d=1 at some point, which you do not

This can be be done multiple ways but simplified would be

```
SET x = 1; // if counting rows
lb: LOOP
  ... your code ...
  if x > 10 THEN SET d = 1;
  else SET  x = x + 1;
END LOOP;
```

Comment: THIS IS OK BUT THE THE SELECTED DATA IS NOT GETTING INSERTED..INTO TEMP TABLE .

Comment: anybody sure of whether cursor works in phpmyadmin ??3.2.0.1

Comment: Have you tried your select statement outside your stored procedure with a value for temp_id and does the temp_magazine_table only have those fields, if not you will need to declare your fields

Comment: thanks for your comments actually the problem is now solved i have used two cursor instead of the second select statement.